# How to execute only if all the statements in try doesn't fail?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
try :
    doSomething1()
    doSomething2()
    doSomething3()
except Exception as e :
    doSomething4()
}
```

I know that in the above code If `doSomething1()` fails `doSomething2() & doSomething3()` won't execute and it would jump to `doSomething4()`.
But I want something where if either on of `doSomething1() or doSomething2() or doSomething2()` fails the whole try doesn't gets executed and jumps to `doSomething4()`
Actually I'm working with a database and in `try` I create two rows but sometimes second row fails and first one doesn't, But I don't want the 1st row to be saved when the second one fails. I want both of them to execute or fail together. How?

Comment: If you work on a database, can't you use a transaction and rollback on error?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you need transactional behaviour. You should do this using the tools available in your database driver, not with naive Python error handling.

Comment: Python can't go back in time. Once something is done, it can't be undone automatically.

Comment: I'm working with Django. Do you know how can I accomplish `transaction and rollback` in Django?

Comment: @pavitran Have you tried [reading the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/)?

Comment: @Tagc No I haven't yet, I will check it out thanks for the help Lucero and Tagc !

Comment: `try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        # ...
        if mal != '':
            raise IntegrityError

except IntegrityError:
    handle_exception()` @Tagc this is what I'm looking for?

Comment: @pavitran I don't know; I don't work with Django. Try it out, and if it doesn't work you can try raising a new question here to address the specific problem(s) you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want that if any of the `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3` method fails, then the `try` block is skipped, and the `doSomething4` method is run.

Well, it's not logically possible. If `doSomething1` fails, then it has been executed, hence the whole `try` can no more be entirely skipped. Same for `doSomething2`: if it fails, then it has been run, and `doSomething1` did not failed, so only `doSomething3` can still be skipped.

Here are a few different behaviours you can implement.

**Behaviour 1**

```
try:
    doSomething1()
    doSomething2()
    doSomething3()
except:
    doSomething4()
```

Tries to run `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3`. If one of them fails, the following ones are skipped, and `doSomething4` is executed. Else, `doSomething4` is skipped.

**Behaviour 2**

```
try:
    doSomething1()
    doSomething2()
    doSomething3()
finally:
    doSomething4()
```

Tries to run `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3`. If one of them fails, the following ones are skipped. In any case, `doSomething4` is executed at the end.

**Behaviour 3**

```
try:
    doSomething1()
except:
    try:
        doSomething2()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            doSomething3()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            doSomething4()
else:
    try:
        doSomething2()
    except:
        try:
            doSomething3()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            doSomething4()
    else:
        try:
            doSomething3()
        except:
            doSomething4()
```

If exactly one of `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3` fails, `doSomething4` is run. This behaviour could be implemented in a much easier way with neater exception management, but this code has the merit of using only `try`s, `except`s and `else`s.

**Behaviour 4**

```
try:
    doSomething1()
    doSomething2()
    doSomething3()
    doSomething4()
except:
    ...
```

This is what corresponds to the title of your question. If none of `doSomething1`, `doSomething2` and `doSomething3` fails, `doSomething4` is run; else, it is not run.